# Using Mac Hotspot for automated testing of mobile devices

Tags: ios, macos, testing, wifi

I've used Apple's Network Link Conditioner to simulate a degraded network for my iOS device testing. But I'd like to set up some automated testing where a Mac's wifi hotspot is used as the mobile device-under-test's wifi connection. I'd like to be able to programmatically disable/enable the wifi network as well as disable/enable the networks upstream connection, perhaps under shell control. Any notion on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my MacBook, which has no built-in Ethernet, the following commands turns the Wi-Fi radio off and on:

`sudo ifconfig en0 down`

`sudo ifconfig en0 up`

If you enable Internet Connection Sharing you can use these commands to disable and enable Wi-Fi, and the backhaul interface as well, you'll just need to figure out which `en` device is which.

For finer grained control over the Wi-Fi radio check out the `airport` tool:

`/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Resources/airport`